# Showing that no non-identity element of $G/F_g$ has finite order where $G$ abelian, $F_g$ the set of elements of G that have finite order

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $F_g$ the set of elements of $G$ that have finite order. Show $F\trianglelefteq G$ and no non identity element of $G/F_g$ has finite order.

$G$ is abelian $\implies F_g$ is abelian. So $g^-1fg =g^-1gf=ef=f \in F_g$. Therefore $F_g \trianglelefteq G$.

The elements of $G/F_g$ are the cosets of $F_g$ in $G$. Let a coset $F_Gx \in G/F_g$ such that $x\not=e$.

Suppose $|F_gx|$ is finite. Then, $\exists q\in \Bbb Z^+$ such that

$(F_gx)^q=F_ge$

$\iff F_gx^q=F_ge$

Kind of stuck here. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: To conclude $F_g$ is normal you don't need that $F_g$ is abelian (since abelian subgroups aren't necessarily normal and normal subgroups aren't necessarily abelian), what you need is that $G$ is abelian implies everything commutes implies conjugations are trivial ($gfg^{-1}=f$ for all $g,f$).

Answer (score 1):

For cosets, $gH=H$ if and only if $g\in H$.